# How to reset page as 1 in React-Query while keyword is entered in Input Field for searching

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using a useEffect to reset page as 1 when a new keyword is entered in the input, then I fire the API to fetch data based on the keyword user entered, why am I doing this? because when user goes to page N, API calls the entered keyword in the page N,

In the below code query only runs on the page 18 whereas it should run on the first page in order to get the data in case there is only 1 page from that data available:

/index?page=18&like=description,keyword&sort=stuffs.created_at,desc

I'm resetting the page by useEffect to set it back to 1 when user entered new Data for each time, is there any better approach to remove this useEffect?

```
const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('');
const filtered = useDebounce(input, 300)
useEffect(() => {
    if (filtered){
        setPage(1)
    }
}, [filtered])
const { data: items, isFetching,isLoading, error, isSuccess } = useQuery(['taxpayer', taxpayer, page, filtered], ()=>index(taxpayer, page, input), {refetchOnWindowFocus: false,keepPreviousData: true, retry: false,enabled: open || Boolean(filtered) ? true : false ,select: (response: any)=> response.data})
```

Comment: Don't worry, you've done everything right. Your code is common practice

Comment: Thanks for your comment Timothy, I kinda feel like this useEffect still can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do it without useEffect:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('');
const filtered = useDebounce(input, 300)

if (filtered && page !== 1){
  setPage(1)
}
```

see [the react docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes)